# Jquery - Selecting elements inside a "<tr>" tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<tr class='spark'>
<td>Hello</td>
<div class="hidden" data-target="1"></div>
</tr>

<tr class='spark'>
<td>World</td>
<div class="hidden" data-target="2"></div>
</tr>
```

Let's assume that this prints a table with "Hello" and "World" as rows.

Using jQuery, I want to select the "hidden" div and get the data-target attribute. I have tried this:

```
$('.spark').click(function()
{
    var item = $('.hidden').attr('data-target');

    alert(item);

    //alert($('.spark').find('.hidden').tagName);

});
```

However, this gives me the same result even though the first one when clicked is "1" and the second is "2".

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Your html is invalid `tr` can't have `div`

```
<tr class='spark'>
    <td>Hello <div class="hidden" data-target="1"></div></td>
</tr>
```

then use a descendant lookup

```
$('.spark').click(function () {
    var item = $('.hidden', this).attr('data-target');
    alert(item);
});
```

```js
$('.spark').click(function() {
  var item = $('.hidden', this).attr('data-target');
  alert(item);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class='spark'>
    <td>Hello
      <div class="hidden" data-target="1"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='spark'>
    <td>World
      <div class="hidden" data-target="2"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

only td and th elements can be used as direct child of tr element. you would need to wrap div element in td first.something like this:

```
<tr class='spark'>
 <td>Hello</td>
 <td><div class="hidden" data-target="1"></div></td>
</tr>
```

Then you can used current clicked elements context along with `.find()` to target the element that lies in clicked tr:

```
$('.spark').click(function(){
  var item = $(this).find('.hidden').attr('data-target');
  alert(item);
});
```

### Working Demo